# Send Tokens through RPC API (Metamask)

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I was doing a USDC transaction on the Ropsten network but in the [Metamask documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/) I didn't see any place where transactions with tokens were directly touched, I was trying some things I found without success. An example of what I found I took from [How to send some custom tokens with MetaMask API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70846974/how-to-send-some-custom-tokens-with-metamask-api)

```js
ethereum.request({
  method: "eth_sendTransaction",
  params: [
    {
      from: ethereum.selectedAddress,
      to: "0x07865c6E87B9F70255377e024ace6630C1Eaa37F",
      data: tokenContract.methods
        .transfer("My Wallet", "0.0001")
        .encodeABI(),
    }
  ]
});
```

The problem here is that tokenContract is not defined and I have no idea how to define it

I also found VERY old and really obsolete answers, where mostly web3js is used (And MetaMask doesn't allow to work with web3js anymore as far as I understand, I've already tried it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example above, `tokenContract` is address of the token that you want to transfer. Each token contract is deployed on some address, see for example [USDT](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7) or [DAI](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f).

Also, web3js does support MetaMask, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499056/1693192) for an example implementation. But [MetaMask no longer injects web3js](https://medium.com/metamask/no-longer-injecting-web3-js-4a899ad6e59e), so that you need to import web3js into the web app separately (previously it was possible to use web3 injected by MM).